# existence of complex structure in dimension 2

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Does an orientable closed 2 manifold always admit a complex structure?﻿

I know that an almost complex doesn' t necessarily give rise to a complex structure(the almost complex structure should be integrable)
I am studying 2 manifolds over R, and I wonder if an almost complex structure always exist?
This almost structure may be chosen integrable?

I ask because there are certain known results on the different possible geometries in dimension 2.I don' t know exactly how these manifolds (closed and orientable) are classifyied, but I know there are three cases.
May be I am confused, and the complex structure is irrelevant to this classification.
Some help please!

Comment: Any orientable closed 2 manifold has a complex structure as a Riemann surface. Loosely speaking the sphere (genus 0) can be equipped with a cx. structure by compactifying $\mathbb{C}$, the torus (genus 1) has many cx. structures as the quotient of $\mathbb{C}$ by a lattice, and surfaces of genus $>1$ have cx. structures as the quotient of the hyperbolic disc by the action of a fuchsian group.

Answer (score 1):

May be this link to WIKIPEDIA covers entirely my question...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Classification_of_closed_surfaces

Orientability should also be taken into account...

Comment: Yes, pretty much...